# average of last x days (beginning of last filled cell)

Tags: excel, indexing, average

I've got a table like this, with sold products like in the image. Now I want to get the average of the last 14 days. For this I got this function, which worked until now: =AVERAGE(INDEX(Q7:NR7;COUNTA(Q7:NR7)-14):NR7)

But now we got an automatic function, which only displays the value, when the day is not in future. So in every cell is that function.

Now the mentioned function above does not work anymore (#DIV/0!), as its counting every cell which has either a value in it or just the function.

How to improve it, so its just taking the last 14 days with a value?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `COUNT(Q7:NR7)` as from [docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTA-function-7dc98875-d5c1-46f1-9a82-53f3219e2509) we have

> If you do not need to count logical values, text, or error values (in other words, if you want to count only cells that contain numbers), use the COUNT function.

If this doesn't work, use `COUNTIF(Q7:NR7;"<>")` to count non-empty cells.